# localStorage and locking

Tags: html, thread-safety, local-storage

Since (html5) localStorage and its equivalencies persist in between tabs and windows, I've thought about using it for message passing.  The problem is that fetch and store are different operations, and therefore not atomic.  I have models that rely on UUID generation, conflict resolutions, and beaconing to do the small subset of what I need to do, but my real question is this:

Since the local storage is a shared memory resource, what are the locking mechanisms available for mutual access?

Comment: Thanks for the change ... the terminology is kind of an alphabet soup right now.  There's IE userData, DOM storage from w3c, HTML5 storage, Flash LocalStorage, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you really need is [Channel Messaging](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/comms.html#channel-messaging), though as far as I'm aware no-one has implemented it yet.  It allows arbitrary client side messaging between scripts.

Comment: This does not however seem to solve the racing issue. Since a browser window now can have its own thread, Channel Messaging can create the same racing issue as localStorage.

Answer (score 12):

Benjamin Dumke-von der Ehe recently came up with some (experimental) locking code for localStorage: http://balpha.de/2012/03/javascript-concurrency-and-locking-the-html5-localstorage/

**Update:** the code link in the article is broken, but [here on Github](https://github.com/elad/LockableStorage) is code, specifically mentioning the article.

Comment: This link is interesting and says a good solution probably uses https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/storage_event so that is a good place to start. The blog post has a *dead link* to some actual code based on a paper.

Comment: The blog post has a dead links.

Answer (score 1):

There aren't any built-in. You'll have to come up with your own locking mechanism. You can off course use any of the existing methods that other people have come up with for other things (like locking in memcache for instance).

Comment: Yes, it appears that the locking mechanisms would have to be maintained server-side; which in a way defeats a primary purpose: that is to be able to propagate information from a Comet style master connection on some single tab to all the other ones.

Comment: umm I'm not sure what you are doing, but localStorage has nothing to do with the server. Regarding comet, I'm not 100% sure but I think if you will have multiple tabs (or windows) opened for the same client, a message pushed to the client should reach all tabs. Depends on what implementation of comet you are using off course.

Comment: Their are connection limits as you know.  Unless you marshal data around the client side, there is a possibility your users will hit these, base on their patterns of interaction with your services.