# atomic operation on window.localStorage

Tags: javascript, cordova, local-storage

Is this possible to do when setting 2 or more values? I am using phonegap and concerned that the user could kill the app while before it finishes setting both values.

I realize that I could use W3C web sql with a transaction but didn't want the overkill of sql for what I am doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, no, there is no locking mechanism.  However, you may want to check out this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4528599/localstorage-and-locking) also, and [this site](http://balpha.de/2012/03/javascript-concurrency-and-locking-the-html5-localstorage/) that it references.  You would be better off with a SQL transaction if persistence of those values in an atomic fashion is vital to your program.

Comment: Preventing multiple writes isn't an issue so I likely won't get much out of that library. I'll look into switching to SQL. 

Thanks.

Comment: Mind the browser support (for both websql and indexeddb)

Answer (score -2):

Protect the writes:

```
localStorage.setItem("writing", "1");

localStorage.setItem("k1", "v1");
localStorage.setItem("k2", "v2");
...

localStorage.removeItem("writing");
```

Then, when loading the DB:

```
if (localStorage.writing != undefined)
{
    treat the DB as corrupted
}
```

Comment: @David Wolever would you care to provide a failing scenario for this code?

Comment: I think this might be quite close to actually implementing a mechanism to detect corruptions in concurrent environment. The `writing` flag should contain some unique token (eg, random number) and then at the end we should check for it still there. Also, we can store a hash of data (eg, CRC, MD5, etc) in one automic field... If we need to deal with all updates, then we would have to implement some sort of journaling....

Comment: @srg: 
1. Tab1 checks if `writing` is undefined, and sees that it is.

2. CPU switches to Tab2. it checks if `writing` is undefined, and sees that it is. It then sets `writing` to 1

3. CPU switches to Tab1. It already saw that `writing` was undefined, so it sets `writing` to 1. It then sets `k1` to 42.

4. CPU switches to Tab2. It sets `k1` to "foobar"

5. CPU switches to Tab1. It reads "foobar" from `k1`.

Comment: IndexedDb support transactions so this atomic behavior should be implementable here. What is needed is method  implement`setIfNull` which will store the id of object which acquires lock of this resource. After it clears it can be acquired by others.